# The bar chart from Sparklines won't load

Tags: javascript, charts, sparklines

I have two charts from [Sparklines](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-about): one as pie and one as bar. The pie chart works fine but the bar chart dosen't even load. On my local web server, the bar chart loads fine. I'm getting no errors at all!

```
<div id="bar"><div id="chart">96,96,96,96,39,48,97,89,96,96,96,60,96,96,96,96,97,96,96,90,80,97,96,98,96,96,96,67,96,96,94,94,96,96,96,96,96,96,96,96</div></div>

$('div#bar > div#chart').sparkline('html', {
    type: 'bar',
    barColor: 'white',
    height: '30px',
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderColor: '#f5f5f5',
    tooltipFormat: '{{value}}'
});
```

You can find the website with the charts [here](https://erik-edgren.nu/disputatio/user/126816473170575360). Only the data for the bar chart are visible. Any idea why it is like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success! It was the double `div#chart` that was the "error". When I changed it to `div#pchart` for the pie chart and `div#bchart` for the bar chart, the bar chart was finally visible!